# Modules which are both left and right modules over a noncommutative ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, terminology, bimodules

Given a noncommutative ring $R$, is there a name for those (left) $R$-modules $M$ for which
$$
m.(rs) = m.(sr), ~~~ \textrm{ for all } r,s \in R, \textrm{ and } m \in M?
$$
(Note that we have denoted the action of $R$ on $M$ by a dot.)
In other words, what does one call modules which are both left and right modules.

Comment: I get your title qustion, but what on earth does $v\lhd (rs)$ denote?  How is $v$ related to $V$? Either way, how does one interpret $(rs)$ as being something that relates to $V$ or its elements, whatever $v$ is?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's a special word for an abelian group which is both a left module and a right module.  Since the two actions are "unrelated" we don't think of them as functioning as a single structure.

But there *is* a special word for an abelian group which is a left and right $R$ module such that $r(ms)=(rm)s$ for all $r,s\in R$, and $m\in M$: this is called an $R, R$ **bimodule.**

You don't have to have the same ring on both sides: it could be two different rings, say $S$ on the right.  And also, you can consider an $R,S$ bimodule structure as simply a left module structure over the ring $R\otimes_\mathbb Z S^{op}$.

---

> No, I think we're talking about different things. I am asking for a (let's say) left $$-module  such that $()=()$, for all $∈$, and $,∈$

Well, that puts extra conditions on the right hand module action.  I would call that "A right $R$ module whose annihilator contains the commutator ideal of $R$," because by what you wrote, $m(rs-sr)=0$ for all $r,s\in R$, $m\in M$.

Again, without some sort of relationship to the left hand action, I'm not aware of a word that encompasses both.

Comment: I'm asking for a representation which is both a left and a right module at the same time. For example, take a representation of a commutative ring.

Comment: @QuinAppleby Yes... I understand that. That's what I'm talking about, right?  For example, every two-sided ideal is a bimodule and, for that matter " a left and right module at the same time"

Comment: No, I think we're talking about different things. I am asking for a (let's say) left $R$-module $M$ such that $m(rs) = m(sr)$, for all $m \in M$, and $r,s \in R$.

Comment: @QuinAppleby Oh... well yeah that is completely different. I'll add something to my answer about it

Comment: @QuinAppleby Are you sure that's what you want? Note that, depending on the ring in question this condition is so strong that it forces $M$ to be trivial. In other words, there are noncommutative rings which are equal to the two-sided ideal generated by commutators, for example matrix rings.

Answer (score 1):

If $k \rightarrow A$ is a commutative $k$-algebra with $k$ a commutative unital ring,
you may consider the tensor product $A(d):=A^{\otimes_k d}$ of $A$ with itself over $k$ d times. There are canonical maps

$$p_i: A \rightarrow A(d)$$

defined by

$$p_i(a):=1\otimes \cdots 1 \otimes a \otimes 1 \otimes \cdots \otimes 1$$

where the $a$ is "placed in position $i$". Here $i=1,..,d$. With this definition you get $d$ commuting $A$-module structures on $A(d)$: You define for any $a\in A$ the $i$'th left multiplication on $A(d)$ as follows. Let $b:=b_1\otimes \cdots \otimes b_d \in A(d)$. define

$$  a^ib:=b_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes ab_i \otimes \cdots \otimes b_d:=p_i(a)b.$$

You get for any elements $u,v\in A$

$$ u^i(v^jb):=p_i(u)(p_j(v)b)=p_j(v)(p_i(u)b)=v^j(u^ib)$$

hence these $d$ module structures commute. Hence you do not need $A$ to be non-commutative. I do not know if there is a word reserved for this structure. Maybe Bourbaki's "Commutative algebra" book can give some answers. They study bimodules and more generally "multi modules" and I believe the above construction is referred to as a multi module.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, your condition amounts to the fact that the action of $R$ on $M$ factors through the "abelianization" of $R$ (not sure if this is standard terminology for rings).

Specifically, for any ring $R$, you can form the ideal $I$ generated by all elements of the form $xy-yx$, and $R^{ab} = R/I$ is then the minimal commutative quotient of $R$.

Then a left $R$-module $M$ is also a right module iff the action of $R$ factors through $R^{ab}$. So studying "left-and-right" modules over $R$ is the same thing as studying modules over the commutative ring $R^{ab}$.